# Card supports OpenGL 4.1 but no GL4 implementation on thread?

Tags: opengl, jogl

**When I run my test JOGL app, it says that I only have GL2 available on the thread when my system supports up to OpenGL 4.1** according to the [OpenGl Extensions Viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opengl-extensions-viewer/id444052073?mt=12).

Does anyone see anything obvious why only GL2 would be supported in the thread?

I am using a mid-2015 Macbook Pro with Intel Iris and AMD Radeon R9 graphics cards.

[image: Intel Iris]

[image: AMD Radeon R9]

This is the very first exercise in the book [Computer Graphics Programming in OpenGL with Java].[4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N6MY65G)

> Java Version: Java8
>
> JOGL Version: 2.3.2
>
> GlueGen Version: 2.3.2

```
import java.nio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;

public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {
    private GLCanvas myCanvas;

    public Code() {
        setTitle("Chapter 2 - program1");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(myCanvas);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        drawable.setGL(new DebugGL4(gl));
        float bkg[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        FloatBuffer bkgBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(bkg);
        gl.glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, bkgBuffer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Code();
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL4 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL4(); // This is where the code fails
        String version = gl.glGetString(GL4.GL_VERSION);
        String shaderversion = gl.glGetString(GL4.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
        System.out.println("GLVERSION: " + version + " shading language: " + shaderversion );
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) { }
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -classpath /private/var/folders/rd/tltb7sk928x_n429dyctdt8c0000gn/T/classpath1.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Code
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Not a GL4 implementation on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.java:1438)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:505)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:559)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
    at sun.lwawt.LWRepaintArea.paintComponent(LWRepaintArea.java:59)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleJavaPaintEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1314)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1198)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4965)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Not a GL4 implementation
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.getGL4(GL4bcImpl.java:40464)
    at Code.init(Code.java:38)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:644)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:667)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1407)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1291)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glActiveTexture(<int> 0x84C0): GL_INVALID_OPERATION ( 1282 0x502),  on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.java:1438)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:505)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:559)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.update(GLCanvas.java:866)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:255)
    at sun.lwawt.LWRepaintArea.updateComponent(LWRepaintArea.java:47)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:232)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleJavaPaintEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1314)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1198)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4965)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glActiveTexture(<int> 0x84C0): GL_INVALID_OPERATION ( 1282 0x502), 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.DebugGL4bc.writeGLError(DebugGL4bc.java:31803)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.DebugGL4bc.glActiveTexture(DebugGL4bc.java:232)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLFBODrawableImpl.swapFBOImpl(GLFBODrawableImpl.java:471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLFBODrawableImpl.swapBuffersImpl(GLFBODrawableImpl.java:426)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableImpl.swapBuffers(GLDrawableImpl.java:88)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1295)
    ... 31 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is interesting, `glxinfo` returns that only OpenGL 2.1 is supported (OpenGL version string: 2.1 ATI-1.42.15) but according to Apple (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823), 4.1 should be supported.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that OSX falls back to OpenGL 2.1 so you need to set the core profile yourself.

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 M370X OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 2.1 ATI-1.42.15
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

I was able to set the core version (OpenGL 4.1) by passing GLCapabilities into the GLCanvas constructor.

Here is the new, fixed constructor:

```
public Code() {
    setTitle("Chapter 2 - program1");
    setSize(600, 400);
    setLocation(200, 200);

    // This was the fix
    GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getMaxProgrammableCore(true);
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
    myCanvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

    myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    this.add(myCanvas);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: It's not really a fix. Choosing a profile when using JOGL is a good practice, it avoids to rely on the default profile.

Answer (score 2):

For running the book's examples on a Mac, I have placed instructions on this website: http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~gordonvs/errataMac.html

In summary, you need to:

- make sure you've installed the latest Java SE
- place the relevant JOGL libraries into System/Library/Java/Extensions  (the particular ones required are listed in the above website)
- add the code described above by Julien (thanks!)
- change the version numbers on the shaders to 410 (or whatever your Mac supports)
- in the examples that use textures, replace the binding layout qualifiers in the shaders to appropriate calls to glUniform1i() in the Java application (for compatibility with version 4.1)

If more idiosyncrasies are identified, I'll add them to the instructions in the website.

Comment: Do NOT put any library into System/Library/Java/Extensions, it's a bad practice as the extension mechanism will be removed from Java 1.9 and it affects all applications and applets in the system as the libraries stored in this directory are loaded before the libraries in the classpath of the application. For example, imagine that you put JOGL 2.3.2 into this directory whereas a particular application requires JOGL 2.4, it might fail to run because JOGL 2.3.2 will be loaded first. This mechanism is cumbersome and error prone, please don't use it.

Comment: I advise you to read that: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/planning-safe-removal-of-under-used-endorsed-extension-directories http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/index.html "This feature has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release"

Comment: Sorry about that -- we had mistakenly thought that Apple's extension folder would continue.  Looks like you're right.  Guess that means that my second bullet should instead say to add the jars to your classpath, or include it on the java command line with the -cp option.  I'll modify the page.

Comment: The Apple's extension folder has been a source of problems anyway. Yes you can set the classpath attribute within the JAR manifest or use the -cp option. Don't forget to use the right delimiter depending on the operating system.